# Bootstrap 5 navbar background color is not changing on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building an angular app in which I am using Bootstrap 5. I created a transparent navbar and I would like to see the background color change from transparent to dark when the page is scrolled. It doesn't work. It still keeps my navbar transparent instead of dark color each time the page is scrolled.

My navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark p-md-3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">WorkonPro</a>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="navbar-toggler"
      data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      arial-controls="navbarNav"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle Navbar"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <div class="mx-auto"></div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active item-space" href="#" aria-current="page"
            >Home</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link item-space" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link item-space" href="#"> Healthcare </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link item-space" href="#">Tech</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="nav-link btn btn-sm item-space grey-button"
            style="color: #fff"
            role="button"
            >Login
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="nav-link btn btn-sm item-space green-button"
            style="color: #fff"
            role="button"
            ><strong>Create account</strong>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The JS script I wrote with the aim to achieve this. (Please note that I wrote the same body of my html page)

```
<script src="../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
      nav.classList.add('bg-dark', 'shadow');
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove('bg-dark', 'shadow');
    }
  });
</script>
```

My style which has to do with the navbar is below:

```
.bg-dark {
  background-color: #101011 !important;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #101011;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
   margin: 0;
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   display: inherit;
}
.navbar-brand {
  color: #101011;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 10px;
}

body .navbar {
  padding: 6px 0 !important;
}

body .navbar-brand {
  background: none;
}
```

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? What did I miss? And how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work fine for me.. Plz check the length of your body.. body height>100vh + 100px is required to run your js because of the condition given
this is exacty your code but it work for me well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .bg-dark {
      background-color: #101011 !important;
    }

    .navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
      padding: 20px 0 10px 10px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: #101011;
    }
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }
    .navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
       margin: 0;
       width: 50%;
       float: left;
       display: inherit;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
      color: #101011;
      padding: 20px 0 10px 10px;
    }

    body .navbar {
      padding: 6px 0 !important;
    }

    body .navbar-brand {
      background: none;
    }
  </style>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body style=height:120vh class="bg-info">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark p-md-3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">WorkonPro</a>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="navbar-toggler"
      data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      arial-controls="navbarNav"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle Navbar"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <div class="mx-auto"></div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active item-space" href="#" aria-current="page"
            >Home</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link item-space" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link item-space" href="#"> Healthcare </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link item-space" href="#">Tech</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="nav-link btn btn-sm item-space grey-button"
            style="color: #fff"
            role="button"
            >Login
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="nav-link btn btn-sm item-space green-button"
            style="color: #fff"
            role="button"
            ><strong>Create account</strong>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
<script>
  var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
      nav.classList.add('bg-dark', 'shadow');
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove('bg-dark', 'shadow');
    }
  });
</script>
```

copy this and paste

Comment: window.pageYOffset > 100 
reduce this to some 80 or 50

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It is still not working for me. I made changes to the body height by changing it from 100% in my style.scss file to 120vh and also changed the window.pageYOffset > 100 to window.pageYOffset > 70 and changed the way i earlier wrote the script at the base of the body to the way you wrote yours and it still didn't work. It worked for you and it is not working for me? i am confused, tbh.

Comment: I dont know why it is so. Are you sure that you tried the code exactly without changing any thing. While i am typing this also i run the above code i posted. It work fine for me. Ok, Did you add anything esle with this some other js or some other css.  Did you insert full bootstrap css or just the thing you mentioned above(i recoment to insert bootstrap.min.css ).

Comment: Are you sure the bootstrap css and js inserted properly ie, the path is correct

Comment: In my angular.json file, my styles and script are written thus:

`"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
              ],
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"                          
            ]`

Answer (score 0):

Just give your navbar an id and type this code it works for me so far

```
// Changing nav color
const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
window.onscroll = (e) => {
 if (window.scrollY > 100) {
 navbar.classList.replace("navbartransparent", "navbarcolored");
 } else {
 navbar.classList.replace("navbarcolored", "navbartransparent");
 }};
```